# how many liters/gallons of beer i can make out of 1 LBS of barely malt syrup ?

Tags: beer

[image]

i am going to use this jar which is the only available malt in the markets , and because its a bit pricey as i mentioned in my last post in decided to get only one .

and i would like to know if there is a "trick" to increase the quantity of liters by adding in the wort stuff like ( Maple syrup , Dates Molasses , Honey ..etc) ?

i might sound silly to you guys so excause me for that i am just a newbie in here ! lol .

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

One pound of liquid malt extract in one gallon of water will typically yield a 1.037 gravity wort.  How well it will ferment is hard to gauge.  I'd recommend putting it into a gallon and a half of water, rinse it out really well with the warm water in the pot.  Then boil it down to 1 gallon with some hops, measure the gravity and ferment it.  If it ferments out all the way then you are in good shape for one gallon beers.

You can make it stronger by adding other fermentable sugars: honey, sugar etc etc.  I'd personally not go more than 20% of the total fermentables being added as pure sugars.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

http://howtobrew.com/book/section-1/malt-extract-and-beer-kits/how-much-extract-to-use

One pound of malt extract (if that is what that is) to one gallon of water to make a light bodied beer...